# How to stream video from IP or any camera to iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ip-camera

I am trying to build a simple app that can stream security camera footage to an iOS app. I don't know if there is a certain kind of camera that will allow it. I believe IO cameras will work. Is it possible to do such a thing with Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Swift is a general purpose programming language. Any software can be written with Swift. iOS also supports everything you need for receiving a video stream. If you have a camera which provides a video stream, look for the standards it uses, and for code accepting that standard as a player.

Comment: Thanks.  So how exactly would I capture a video stream to my ios app? Are there any certain libraries I need to use? Is there any documentation that I can find on them?

Comment: Apple's framework is called AVFoundation. https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/

Comment: Thank you John, I'll take a look!